# Deleting namespace and remove release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I wonder the purpose of adding clean up stage in Jenkins CI/CD pipeline to remove release if exist with `helm delete` command. What is the main purpose ans use case that we need to clean up the environment that we would like to deploy?  Is that still necessary for using `upgrade install` command for helm.

```
helm upgrade --install a-service
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `helm delete $RELEASE_NAME` it deletes all resources but keeps the record with $RELEASE_NAME in case you want to rollback. You can see removed releases via `helm ls -a` . Whereas `helm delete --purge $RELEASE_NAME` removes records and make that name free to be reused for another installation.

If your initial release ends up in a failed state then running `helm upgrade --install a-service` will throw error

```
$ helm upgrade "foo" . --install 
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "foo" has no deployed releases
```

Then you need clean it up using

```
helm delete foo --purge
```

Comment: So, can we say add clean up stage essential for to avoid this error message in case of failed releases using following command likewise 'helm delete ${release}'

Comment: Yes to make deployment  idempotent

Comment: In Helm 3, [`helm uninstall` deletes internal state by default](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/faq/#cli-command-renames) and you need to explicitly `--keep-history`; this is the opposite of the Helm 2 `helm delete [--purge]` behavior.